# Max connection per host in Cassandra Driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

Will there be an issue in increasing **max connection per host** in Cassandra driver?

Currently I set to 2 (Default) and I could see there is no 'Request timed out' error in Cassandra but when I increase it to 32, I see request timed out error in Cassandra, I believe increasing connection should give better performance why it is acting weird?

What are the impacts of increasing Max connection per host in Cassandra driver?

Cassandra : 3.0.8
Driver : c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your getting busy pool exceptions, increasing the number of connections will likely just make problems worse (1 connection can possibly service thousands of requests in parallel). The defaults are pretty optimal for most use cases and its rare to ever need to change them.

The request timeouts are more likely caused from your data model or some insufficient resources.

Comment: my point is increasing connection results in request timed out in client driver but when I set it to 2 default then there is no request timeout in client side, as per my study increasing connection timeout should increase the problem in server side but I hit to the issue in client side why so?

Comment: What are the consequence of increasing connection timeout in client side?

Comment: Request Timeout is an error returned by the server, not the client. Your probably overloading your coordinator because you have some insufficient resource (cpu, memory, disk, jvm heap pressure etc) and adding connections is making it worse.

Comment: If it's an error from server than why it's not logged in server logs? It is an error in client side.

Comment: Cassandra doesn't log every error or details on individual requests since its designed to handle 100's of thousands of requests a second. There are metrics you can look at to see timeouts and timeout rate, but it doesn't put individual ones in the log file. Imagine a 2 sec GC that would suddenly timeout 1000 requests, what would that look like in system.log? The timeout is returned to the client from the coordinator, and the client propagates it up.

Comment: Oh got it, then how can I get all these errors in logs? Or identify these errors in serverside?

Comment: look at [read/write timeout metrics](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#client-request-metrics). If you want it in logs, you will have to build a custom version of cassandra to add that functionality.